# JS function prevents me from changing div height with @media screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making a website with a fixed menu on top. When the page get's resized to the point where that menu don't fit, a new dropdown menu appear to take it's place. In order to open and close said dropdown menu you have to click a button with the following onclick JavaScript function:

```
function showMenu() {
    var mb = document.getElementById("menu-bar");

    if (mb.style.height != "505px") {
        mb.style.height = "505px";
    } else {
        mb.style.height = "70px";
    }
}
```

the issue I am having is when/if the user were to resize the page to the point where the button disapear while the dropdown menu is still open. My first thought was to change the menu-bar height using @media screen like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1301px) {
    #menu-bar {
        height: 70px;
    }
}
```

but due to the JavaScript already controlling the height of the menu-bar this doesn't work. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: The [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the inline styles is higher than rules in the sheets have. It looks like you need to create a couple of classes defining the height to the stylesheet, and change the class of the element instead of inline style properties in JS.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that I should toggle between two classes with two different heights when I click the button? If so, do you have an example on how I could achieve this? Any idéas are welcome since I'm fairly new to HTML, CSS and js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList